# 2 different problems on getting specific cards out of a deck of 52

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

I encountered these two problems and am wondering why we cannot use the same strategy to solve both.

The first one is

> You are dealt a hand of four cards from a well-shuffled deck of 52
> cards. Specify an appropriate sample space and determine the
> probability that you receive the four cards J, Q, K, A in any order,
> with suit irrelevant.

and the textbook solution for this is $\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}$.

The second problem is

> You draw at random five cards from a standard deck of 52 cards. What
> is the probability that there is an ace among the five cards and a
> king or queen?

But here, using the same kind of formula to get one ace out of four possible, and one queen or king out of 8 possible, so $\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{1}\binom{39}{3}}{\binom{52}{5}}$, leads to the wrong answer than the one in the textbook.

What is the difference between these two problems and why is the intuition for the second one wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: The question doesn't necessitate that there be *exactly* one ace, neither does it assert that there can't be *both* kings and queens.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me now!